# Where should I place mountains and deserts in this generated map?

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, map-making, tectonics

Thanks for all the comments and I've re-edited the question:

All nature settings(radius of planet, etc) are similar to the real world earth except the continent layout.

I used Mogensen Planet Generator for the map and recolored it. I am aware that this generator does not consider tectonics, mountain chains, rivers, and climate. So I am mostly concerned about the following elements:

1) Mountains:
This seems the priority because it determines the landscape. So far it is determined by fractal generator and it doesn't look very realistic to me.(Just random elevations and there isn't a tectonic pattern) Given such a layout, what is the approach to determine the moutains and valleys?
2) Deserts:
Seems many comments have pointed out this problem. Is there a specific region you believe that is impossible to have deserts, or must have deserts?

And if you noticed any other errors in my map, please let me know, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi @J.Y, welcome to Worldbuilding! Hope you enjoy your stay, be sure to check out the [help] and the [tour] if you haven't done so already. One of my main concerns are your vast deserts by the ocean. Why are they there?

Comment: Thanks @JavaScriptCoder , I need a large desert somewhere for my story, but I'm not sure where I could put it.

Comment: Deserts are normally in the interior of a continent, possibly in the rain shadow of some mountains.

Comment: where to put a desert would be a much better question than what you have.

Comment: here's a tip for you. look at our own world map and look where the different biomes are, take in account the world equator line because that will help you where to place the biomes you want

Comment: This is in the VTC queue with a vote for [POB](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/idea-refinement-clarification-and-examples-of-vtc-reasons-for-new-users/6437#6437).  I need to disagree, we're missing a bit of information (nature of sun, distance from sun, axial tilt, etc.) and climate is ENORMOUSLY complex, but this Q has objective answers.  What it is, is too broad.  Let's help fix that.  J.Y., This site works best with specific questions.  "Am I missing anything?" questions are regularly closed.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @JBH All right, I will try to re-edit it later. I think my question will basically focus on the distribution of mountains and deserts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm...about the deserts. General rule of thumb is that they happen mostly along 30 degree latitude. There are different types of deserts as well. They can exist by being on the rain shadow side of mountains, but there are also coastal deserts. These are created by the water being too cold to evaporate. An example is the 'Namib desert.'

[Deserts and how they form](http://www.eniscuola.net/en/argomento/desert/desert-biome/desert-formation/)

Another thing to keep in mind is that not all places we might think of as deserts are actually deserts. You have arid climates and semi-arid climates. The semi-arid climate is a sort of buffer zone between an arid and another climate type.

I found this a pretty good site to learn the climate types and where to put them. [Semi-Arid climate types for kids](https://sites.google.com/site/climatetypes/semiarid)

The problem you are going to have with these auto-generated map is that almost none of them account for climate. So the most I found them to be good for is to get the rough edge.

Best way to learn about climate is by looking at real world maps and asking yourself 'Why is this place a desert? Why is there a rainforest on one side and a steppe on the other side? Why are winters in Western Europe generally mild, whilst in Eastern Europe you're getting massive snowfall?"

Some other things to be wary off. They both determine how much rain there will be.
[Ocean currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_current)
[Wind currents](http://www.classroomatsea.net/general_science/conveyor.html)

Best advice I can give you is take your fantasy map, take a real world map and start comparing the two.